# Foward all mail to smarthost and use fetchmail to fetch mail from isp

Tags: linux, sendmail

I want to setup a mail server. Problem is their domain is part of a national company and all the branches use the same domain.

The setup we are using for the server consist of SOGo, Dovecot, Sendmail, Fetchmail and then we use LDAP to authenticate against. I need a way to send all outgoing mail to smart host and still be able to use fetch mail to pull mail from ISP and deliver to the users

What config must i change / add in sendmail or fetchmail to forward the domains mail out? Or are there other ways to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  You want Sendmail to send all mail to a downstream smarthost? There's a configuration parameter for that in the `sendmail.mc` file.

Comment: Yes but if the mail address is the same as the domain it will try and deliver local and not to ISP, not all mail boxes are on the local server. I now realize that if I change my server domain name it will forward all mail out and I can use fetchmail to deliver the mail to the local users. Will test this today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not release that IMAP copies the send email to the sent folder and that it does not need to be send via the same server as the incoming mail.

So all I had to to do was to use their ISP's mail server as SMTP server and this ensured the mail of the same domain that I dont look after does not end up on the local server.